# jQuery - create a 'shimmering' effect over several boxes, smoothly

Tags: jquery

I have a 9 x 6 grid of solid colour blue boxes. When you mouse-over a box, the solid blue fades out and reveals a photograph underneath. The fading is currently done with CSS `:hover` and `transition`.

On page load, the user will not know there are images hidden under the boxes, so I want to 'shimmer' a random selection of boxes.

- When the page loads, a random amount of boxes should be chosen
- Each box should `fadeOut()` to reveal the photograph over the course of 100ms
- Once faded out, it should immediately `fadeIn()` again to cover the photograph
- The next random element should then do the same effect

I think if 20 or so of these ran in quick succession it would look neat. Here is the code I have so far:

jQuery Random plugin:

```
jQuery.fn.random = function() {
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.length);
    return jQuery(this[randomIndex]);
};
```

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // 'Shimmer' the boxes on the homepage
    if($('div#box-container').length > 0) {
        for(i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
            shimmer($('div#box-container div.box-overlay').random().delay(500));
        }
    }
    function shimmer(object) {
        object.fadeIn(100).delay(250).fadeOut(100);
    }

});
```

This code works, but has several issues:

- The fade effect is not smooth - it flashes between full opacity and full transparency
- Immediately, the effect seems to apply to about 6 of the boxes. The remaining 14 then flash about over the next few seconds.

I'm sure there must be a smooth and efficient way to do this - any ideas?

Comment: What about creating CSS animation of shimmer and just apply this class with delay? (CSS animations are smoother) Even delay you could do with adding different classes.

Comment: There is nothing setting a different delay in your loop

Comment: @Volvox Unfortunately, I need IE8 compatibility if at all possible. So CSS animations are a last resort.

Comment: @Popnoodles I thought the `.delay(500)` would trigger it to hold-off on hitting the next iteration of the loop. I think I'm wrong about this - how would it be done properly?

Comment: You need to use the iterator `delay(i * 500)`

Comment: In case you're shuffling these images, this might be useful http://jsfiddle.net/C6LPY/2/